# Android Реакция на PUSH уведомления или как в сервисе узнать что запущена активити

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-binder, activity-service-connection

Использую стандартный GCM от Google.
Так же использую стандартный пример, который приведен в мануале.

К примеру у меня есть 2 типа сообщений - А и Б.
Различаю я их специальным полем в сообщении json.

Вопрос, я хочу сделать так:
**Если приходит тип сообщения А**, то мы НЕ реагируем на сообщение, но если в данный момент запущено приложение то связываемся с активити и говорим ему, чтобы он обновился.

**Если приходит тип сообщения Б**, то всегда выводим - Notification сообщение.

Как разделить сообщения понятно, но как понять, в данный момент мое приложение запущено, если да, то как получить активное активити???

Приведу код для примера как я это реализовываю:

*В примере пока нет разделения на типы сообщений, потому что это не так важно пока. Представим что все наши сообщения типа - А.*

**Манифест**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="ru.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ru.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <!--<category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="ru.gcmtest.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="ru.gcmtest.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="ru.gcmtest.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>


</application>
```

**Активити**

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "main";
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                        .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (sentToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.token_error_message));
                }
            }
        };

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Основные классы, приведу тот где я получаю сообщение**

```
import ...

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        //String message = data.get("price").toString();
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_ic_googleplayservices)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. `GcmListenerService` расширяет `Service` его можно стандартным способом связать с активити через `Binder`.

При этом в активити реализуется стандартный интерфейс подключения/отключения от сервиса [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html). В нём при подключении к сервису присваиваем `boolean` полю сервиса значение `true`. В `onSop()` (или `onPause()`) активити присваивайте полю сервиса `false`.

Так как при переходе с одной активити `A` на активити `B` порядок вызовов будет таким: `A.onPause()` -> `B.onStart()` -> `B.onResume()` -> `A.onStop()`. То:

Если активити несколько и нужно только `A`, то надо `onPause`. Или если нужно активити любое. Если активити одна, то, вроде, и `onStop` подойдёт

Таким образом у вас в сервисе всегда будет `true` если активити запущена и `false` во всех остальных случаях. По умолчанию поле сие должно быть `false`

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под этим " стандартный интерфейс подключения/отключения" ?

Comment: @researcher, [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html)

Comment: В данном случае я бы даже не заморачивался с подключением к сервису через `Binder`, а просто завел бы в нем `static` поле с флагом.

А вот по поводу работы с этим полем в `onStart()`/`onStop()` или в `onResume()`/`onPause()` настоятельно не советую делать это в `onStart()`/`onStop()` так как при переходе с одной активити A на активити B порядок вызовов будет таким: A.onPause() -> B.onStart() -> B.onResume() -> A.onStop(). И следовательно в первом случае поле будет  `false` не смотря на то что активити B запущено.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял, спасибо.

Comment: @xkor, да, если активити несколько и нужно только `A`, то надо `onPause`. Или если нужно активити любое. Если активити одна, то, вроде, и `onStop` подойдёт.

Comment: @xkor, добавил это в ответ. А статикам я не доверяю)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, откуда же такое недоверие к стандартным механизмам языка? Или это от того что не вписывается в сферический ООП?)

Comment: @xkor, я просто где-то что-то слышал про утечки памяти... А т.к. знаний у меня не достаточно для понимания правду говорят али нет, то я их просто опасаюсь) Опасаюсь, но использую... В основном в качестве констант)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хех, ну для утечек надо как минимум в статические поля объекты пихать, ну и не удалять вовремя. А с примитивами утекать в общем то нечему)

Comment: @xkor, ну, коли так, то решение со статическим полем будет изящнее) Но (вот только в голову пришло) если сервис умрёт во время после `onResume` активити и до его `onPause` то, даже если он пересоздастся, то поле его статическое будет, всё же, инициализировано, по умолчанию, `false`?

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Вектор понятен. Только вот я нигде явно GcmListenerService как сервис не стартую. Я реализовал метод ServiceConnection, и в методе onStart прописал - bindService(intent, sConn, 0); - intent конечно же intentServerGCM = new Intent(main.this, MyGcmListenerService.class);  Но ничего не произошло. Коннект не отрабатывает.

Comment: @inkognitum, да, перед подключением к сервису его надо стартануть. При этом, если он запущен уже, то повторный вызов `startService` не перезапустит текущий а лищь вызовет его метод onStartCommand.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, статические поля на то и статические что на них никак не влияет создание и умирание экземпляров. Они эквивалентны глобальным переменным, их значения только перезапуск процесса может сбросить.

Comment: @xkor, т.е. если у сервиса будет поле `private static boolean actIsRunning = false;` и он умрёт и возродится пока действует активити (т.е. не полным убийством процесса всего приложения), то при создании нового экземпляра класса будет проигнорирована инициализация поля этого, и у него будет сразу, в конструкторе, `true`? Коли так, то мне надо теорию подучить(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну инициализация статик полей происходит при инициализации класса (его загрузке), а не при инициализации экземпляров, так что боюсь что Вам действительно стоит немного повторить теорию)

Comment: @xkor, видимо да) Спс за разъяснения)